# WCF IErrorHandle asynchronous issue

Tags: wcf, ierrorhandler

As far as I know, HandleError is supposed to run asynchronously against service but following code proves that is run on the same thread what service does : both methods display 4 as thread number and what is more HandleError hangs service.

```
class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(55555);
       Debug.WriteLine("Handle : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
       return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Provice : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you believe that `HandleError` is run asynchronously?   From  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.handleerror(v=vs.110).aspx): "Because the HandleError method can be called from many different places there are no guarantees made about which thread the method is called on. Do not depend on HandleError method being called on the operation thread."  I don't see anything in MSDN specifying that it runs asynchronously.

Comment: I had such feeling after reading this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801898/WCF-Global-Exception-Handling-using-IErrorHandler "HandlerError is called asynchronously on a separate thread,"

Comment: That is contrary to what MSDN says, and your testing would indicate that's not the case as well.